# passing an array of jquery get requests into $.when()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following parameters:

```
a = [{param:'a'}, {param:'b'}, {param:'c'}]
```

I'd like to make a get request for each parameter, like this:

```
a.map(function(ai){return $.get('myapi/get?ai='+ai.param)})
```

How do I do something once all the get requests have finished?

I have tried using $.when, like this:

```
$.when(
    a.map(function(ai){return $.get('myapi/get?ai='+ai)})
)
.done(function(results){
    results.forEach(function(ri, i){
        ri.success(function(result){
            a[i].result = result
        }
    }
    do_something_with(a)
}
```

unfortunately I am clearly misunderstanding this `$.when().done()` idiom as when I call `do_something_with(a)` I don't have the new `.result` attribute. I'm guessing it's because `when` is seeing a single array and so just passes straight into the `.done()`, as opposed to waiting for each component `get` to finish.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `ri.success` supposed to be? `ri` is the result returned by the AJAX call (or would be, if not for other errors in the code), not a deferred/`jqXHR` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
$.when.apply($, myArray);
```

i.e. using `Function.apply` to call `$.when()` with `this === $` and the rest of the arguments being the *contents* of the array `myArray`, where that array contains the deferred objects returned by each call to `$.get`.

---

To answer the second question from your comments, you could pass your array of deferred objects through this map function, which returns a *new* array of deferred objects which will be resolved at completion of each AJAX call, regardless of whether it succeeded or not.

```
var alwaysDef = def.map(function(old) {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    old.always(def.resolve);
    return def;
});
```

Note that I'm not sure what parameters (if any) will end up being passed to the final `.done` function in this instance.

If that matters, the deferred objects are always called in order, so you can register a `.done` handler for each of the original promises that stores the AJAX results in an array for later use, and a `.fail` handler that stores a `null` value instead.

That will ensure that your final `.when` handler isn't invoked until after each of the individual results are available to you.

Comment: that was FAST! I use the same trick when dealing with the response in .done()?

Comment: @MikeDewar in `.done()` you'll need to use the `arguments` pseudo-array to retrieve the response data - AFAICR one for each AJAX call.

Comment: use console.log(arguments) within the done callback to see what the arguments contain. It should be an array of objects or arrays.

Comment: is there an approach that doesn't mind terribly if one or more of the promises fails? Seems like .done and .then are both quite sensitive to a failed response

Comment: @MikeDewar yes - you have to create a new `Deferred` for each request that you `.always()` `.resolve()` and then go do your stuff only `.when()` _those_ deferred objects are all `.done`. ;-)